# Parallel mapply() for Windows; like mcmapply()

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, apply

I am wondering if there is a version of `mapply()` that works in parallel for Windows. The `parallel` package has great options for parallelizing `apply` functions, but it seems to leave out a Windows option for `mapply()`. The `parallel` package has `mcapply` functions for non-Windows users (ie `mcapply()`, `mclapply()`, `mcmapply()`, etc), and `parApply` functions for Windows users (ie `parApply()`, `parLapply()`, etc.). There is no `parLapply()`, though.

Is there an equivalent to `mcmapply()` for Windows?

Here are two lists:

```
list1 <- list(elem1 = 1:3, elem2 = 4:6, elem3 = 7:9)
list2 <- list(elem1 = 10:12, elem2 = 13:15, elem3 = 15:17)
```

I want to add them together;

```
(result <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y){
  x + y
}, list1, list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

How can I recreate this in parallel for Windows users?

Note: `parApply` functions are not drop-in replacements like `mcapply` functions. See the link for good documentation on how to use them.
[https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html](https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ejerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(disclaimer: I'm the authur)

The [**future.apply**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package provides one-to-one parallel versions of all of R's apply functions.  Since it operates on top of the [**future**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework, it works with basically all known parallel backends in R.

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multicore)  ## forked processing

list1 <- list(elem1 = 1:3, elem2 = 4:6, elem3 = 7:9)
list2 <- list(elem1 = 10:12, elem2 = 13:15, elem3 = 15:17)

(result <- future_mapply(FUN = function(x, y){
  x + y
}, list1, list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

The above uses forked processing, just like `parallel::mcmapply()`.  To use PSOCK cluster workers, which is also supported on MS Windows, have the end-user set:

```r
plan(multisession)
```

With the above, you don't have to do conditional coding like:

```r
if (parallel == "forks") {
  ...
} else if (parallel == "this") {
  ...
} else if (parallel == "that") {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

All you need is a single `future_mapply()` call.

Comment: @ HenrikB, that solution works on my simple example. I am having an issue with my real scenario though. I am getting this error: Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'myExpl1' of mode 'function' was not found. It is as if the global environment is not being shared with all the sessions. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Here my code; myBiomodData <- future_mapply(fun = function(a, b, d){
  write.csv(as.matrix(print(system.time(w <- mapply(FUN = function(e, f, g){
    mapply(FUN = function(h, i, j){
      mapply(FUN = function(k, l, m){
        BIOMOD_FormatingData(resp.var = l,
                             expl.var = k,
                             resp.name = m,
                             resp.xy = myRespXY)
      }, h, i, j, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    }, e, f, g, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  }, a, b, d, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))), "myBiomodData_time.csv")
}, myExpl1, myResp1, myRespName1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

Comment: 1. It's possible to explicitly specify additional globals that the future framework fail to detect automatically (see help for that).  2. If you could produce a *minimal* *reproducible* example that I can reproduce, then I can look into the problem and possibly even fix upstream. SO comments is not good for this, so feel free to post to the **future.apply** issue tracker.

Comment: I applied the `future_mapply()` but the result was even slower than the nested `for` loop, even with `vectorized 3 input arguments` (the rest was put inside `MoreArgs =... `). Do you have any ways to suggest speeding up this function?

Comment: @user177196, what's the function you're applying to each iteration? If each call is expected to only take a very short time, the overhead from parallel processing becomes significant and it's not worth doing parallel processing

Comment: @HenrikB the function called `Opt()` which is a user-defined function containing 8 other user-defined functions each compute a lot of things and uses a ton of `dplyr %>% select %>% summarise()`, `data.table` and `scales.` I don't think it is simple.

Comment: Point is, if each call to `Opt()` takes only a brief moment, then it's not worth parallelizing. Lots of code is not worth parallelizing. Only you know how long `Opt()` takes. Compare `future_mapply()` to `mapply()` to get a sense, if the former is worth it.

Comment: @HenrikB 1.96 minutes per run. Is that long enough Professor HenrikB? Also, can you tell me how to circumvent the conflict between `future_mapply(..., future.scheduling = 2)` with `data.table()` as I kept getting the error like `setallocol(x)` when putting in this parameter? I tried `mapply` and it outperforms `future_mapply()` so I am really sad.

Comment: Yes, 2 minutes is long enough. It should definitely run faster in parallel.  If it's slower, it could be that you're running into other bottlenecks, e.g. running low on memory causing lots of file swapping.  BTW, note that *data.table* already runs in parallel, so if the 2 minutes are spent on **data.table**, it won't help running another layer of parallelization on top of it.   For the **data.table** issue, see https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions/621#discussioncomment-2715653.

Comment: I think you are likely to be correct on the `data.table` part :) Many thanks Professor HenrikB.

Comment: @HenrikB: also, I am quite interested in *any* examples you might have on how to apply `foreach....dopar` on a `for` loop within a function, such that this `for` loop contains some big functions that contain quite a few small functions (e.g. `Opt()` contains functions `A(), B(), C(), D(), E(), F()` where `A(), B(), C()` are in `X.R` file and the other `D(), E(), F()` are in the other `Y.R` file, where `Opt()` are in `Z.R` file). I am highly curious whether `doFuture` can help me by avoiding `.export` and `.packages`, as there are so many of them all in the `.local` environment.